# How to get a particular value of an object of this example

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have the following code.

```
private void relacion() throws Exception {
    AlumnoDAO alumnodao = new AlumnoDAO();
    for (int i = 0; i < alumnodao.listar().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(alumnodao.listar().get(i));
    }
}
```

Which returns me an ArrayList of objects.
But I need access to such name.

[image]

You see me back, id, last name etc ..
But I specifically want the name. I am not sure how.
I'm working with POJO

Comment: *Which returns me an ArrayList of objects* -- No, the method returns `void`.

Comment: Do you have a `POJO` class? Then what it's name. I think your `alumndao.listar()` method returns a list of POJO class, then what is the name of `POJO` class. In this case the class should have a property named `name'

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
System.out.println(alumnodao.listar().get(i).id); // access the 'id' field

System.out.println(alumnodao.listar().get(i).nombre); // access the 'nombre' field

System.out.println(alumnodao.listar().get(i).apelidos); // access the 'apelidos' field
```

You may need to use a **getter** to access your arraylist's object member variables depending on their ***visibility***.

Answer (score 0):

The `get` method of `ArrayList` returns an object, whose `public` fields can get accessed. For this reason, you can access the name of the returned object by doing the following:

```
System.out.println(alumnodao.listar().get(i).nombre);
```

However, in most cases you don't want to have your fields declared as `public`. What is usually done instead is to have the fields declared as `private` and access them with `getters` and `setters`.

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(alumnodao.listar().get(i).id);
  symbol:   variable id
  location: class Object